# Error when calling model.labels in KMeans

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I am running this code

```
import pandas as np
import numpy as np

from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

model = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=10)
```

Then I put that through a dataframe I am working on and that includes the columns age and income, which is the clusters I am working on,

```
model.fit(df[['income', 'age']]
```

And so far it works well until I run the following bit, which aims at creating a column with the label of the cluster each data point belongs to.

```
df['cluster'] = model.labels_df.head()
```

And this is the error code I get:

```
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_df'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute to access the labels of the model is: `model.labels_`

**Use:**

```
df['cluster'] = model.labels_
```

By typing `model.labels_df.head()` you request the head of `model.labels_df` that does not exist.

*I believe you have mistyped it and you need:*

```
df['cluster'] = model.labels_
df.head()
```